# Python/Flask Parse response for a specific element

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I'm getting a R response from a Flask request.

```
R = requests.post(url)
```

I'd like now to parse R content

How can I've got the content of a specif `<div>` tag, i.e. for example `<div class='XXX'>`

```
...
<div class='XXX'>
    Raoul
</dev>
...
```

So in this example, I'd like to retrieve `Raoul`.

How can I do that?

R succeed, and R is not null. But I've got `R.raw.data = b''`, which I don't understand, as R.text return me the correct body of the respond.

Thanks in advance,
Raoul

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a library. The standard library for doing this is [Beautiful Soup 4](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/). The docs are very thorough, and you can basically do it by:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(R.data, 'html.parser')
your_divs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "XXX"})
```

Comment: Is there no solution with Flask or urlib ?

Comment: Of course there is, but there's a reason you want to use BS4. If not, you'll basically end up re-writing much of the library. Much of the problem with parsing HTML is that it's non-standard, and you'd need to spend a huge amount of time with regex to get a fully implementable version that won't miss possible permutations that a server might give you. If you're extremely worried about speed/efficiency/etc... you probably don't want to be developing in flask/python in the first place.

Comment: No, I mean, of course BS4 should do the trick, I'm just surprised that seem to me a common task, is not natively included in Flask or urllib.

Comment: It certainly seems like an oversight, but HTML parsing is so difficult it definitely calls for one, universal library, that can be easily updated whenever new HTML standards are created or deprecated.